# Why doesn't parameter value get replaced?

Tags: javascript, node.js, loopback

I have this snippet of code

```
function(memo, value, key) {
    if (!!value) {
      memo.push({
        'property': 'loopbackFilter',
        'value': {
          key : {
            'like' : '%' + value + '%'
          }
        }
      });
    }
    return memo;
  }
```

Sublime Text says that "key" parameter is not being used, and in fact the resulting JSON object is

```
"where": {
  "key": { <--- key is literally "key"
    "like": "%value%" (VALUE is an actual value, so it works here)
  }
}
```

Why does this happen?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

JS object literals are different than JSON objects: In JavaScript you don't need to quote the property names:

```
var obj = { foo: "bar" }
```

For [computed property names](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Object_initializer#Computed_property_names) use the bracket syntax:

```
[key] : {
  'like' : '%' + value + '%'
}
```

Please also note that this is an ES6 feature.

Comment: Just a pointer, you currently does not enough reps to close, but when you do get them, **Please choose to close** instead of answering.

Comment: Alright, thanks for the hint!

Comment: Thank you for the answer,
is there another way to do this?
My app crashes when I try to compile it and I think it's because it's an EC6 only solution

Comment: Yes, there is! See this answer for how to do it with ES5: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2274242/using-a-variable-for-a-key-in-a-javascript-object-literal

Comment: Thank you Christian! Question closed